# How to play first n seconds of a mp3 track with systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd, cron-task, mplayer

Here's my try:

```
[Unit]
Description=play the a team song

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mpg123 /home/pi/Music/the_a_team.mp3
RuntimeMaxSec=10
```

The song plays 21 seconds and then stops. I don't get it.
I also didn't find another solution like telling mpg123 to play just the first n seconds. Please help me. Any solution is fine.

Comment: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) would be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Unit]
Description=play the a team song

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffplay /home/pi/Music/the_a_team.mp3 -t 10 -autoexit -nodisp
```

Note that ffplay is part of the ffmpeg package.

Comment: awesome, on the raspberry it was hard to get ffmpeg somehow, but aplay (alsa) has the same feature :)